# Apache2 - Trouble Adding Subdomain

Tags: linux, apache, webserver, subdomain, virtualhost

I have a Linode server running Ubuntu 11 and Apache2 and I'm trying to get a subdomain working. This is my `mywebsite` file in `sites-available` folder. I've tried putting the top part in its own file `testing.mywebsite` and reloading apache2 with no luck.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /home/user2/www
    ServerName testing.mywebsite.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin email@gmail.com
    ServerName  mywebsite.com
    ServerAlias *.mywebsite.com
    ServerAlias 192.155.90.135

    #Index file and Document Root (where the public files are located)
    DirectoryIndex  index.html index.php
    DocumentRoot    /home/user/public/mywebsite/www

    #Log file locations
    LogLevel    warn
    ErrorLog    /home/user/public/mywebsite/log/error.log
    CustomLog   /home/user/public/mywebsite/log/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I have a website up and running and apache can find all the files in `/home/user/public/mywebsite/www` but when I go to the testing subdomain, my browser can't find it. I'm pretty unfamiliar with apache2, so any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are your DNS records configured to point your computer at the desired hostname to your server's IP address when it resolves? Or, are you overriding with editing */etc/hosts*?

I am somewhat unsure what "my browser can't find it" means, so please clarify if the above questions don't get you closer to your problem. It would be worth checking your log files for Apache in your specified paths and /var/log/apache2/.

Comment: I'm not overriding anything in /etc/hosts but I forgot that the DNS was managed on the Linode website. I set up a new A record and hopefully that will fix the issue. Thanks.